# angular2 bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the angular2 bootstrap date picker when I blur out of the input field. There is no event as (blur) for angular and typescript. Ive tried using d2.toggle() but it doesnt work.

```
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" placement="bottom-right" [(ngModel)]="model2" ngbDatepicker 
         #d2="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d2.open()" >
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuBZw29evPR3RlIcUww2?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a directive which will listen to the clicks on outside of the datepicker.
The main point is to check whenever the DOM element, that receives the click, is the one which has the directive on it.

**Directive:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    clickOutside = new EventEmitter<Event>();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
}
```

And add it like so:

**HTML:**

```
   <input (clickOutside)="d2.toggle()" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" placement="bottom-right" [(ngModel)]="model2" ngbDatepicker 
         #d2="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d2.toggle()" >
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JEF5Y7enZrNsoGbYHdzo?p=preview)

Comment: sure.. the plunkr works but now that I have 2 date pickers.. it is displaying both date pickers.. Its in http://plnkr.co/edit/gjyNnAG9wqucbyyFgl85?p=preview

Comment: I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `Blur` method in angular like this

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" placement="bottom-right" [(ngModel)]="model2" ngbDatepicker 
             #d2="ngbDatepicker" (blur)="onBlurMethod()" (click)="d2.toggle()" >
```

and then do whatever you want to do in that method.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with two datepickers, you can wrap the both and set the directive on the wrapper. Then control openings/closings with a flag:

**HTML**:

```
<div (clickOutside) = "open === 1 ? d.toggle() : open ===2 ? d2.toggle() : null; open =0">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" 

  placeholder="From:" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
  (click)="open === 2 ? d2.toggle() : null; d.toggle();open = 1" required><br />


   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toDate" name="toDate" 
  placeholder="To:" [(ngModel)]="toDate" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker"
  (click)="open === 1 ? d.toggle() : null; d2.toggle();open = 2" required>
</div>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZmwuZOwOJvZwz80yrGnw?p=preview)**